# How to tell search engines which is the main menu?

Tags: seo

I wanted to implement the following structure on my website:

```
<h1>Site Title</h1>
<ul id="menu>
<li>Section 1</li>
<li>Section 2</li>
<li>Section 3</li>
</ul>
```

I have several `<ul>` on the same page. So, I added `<h1>` to the `<ul>` which contains main menu and I was thinking that this will be easy for search engines to find the main menu. Many sources say that there should not be more than one `<h1>` tag on each page and `<h1>` must be different on each page. If it's true, how can I tell to search engines that the main menu is located inside of `<ul id="menu>` and not inside of some another `<ul>`?

I just checked my website in Google and it shows 6 links below the title which look like section names but they are not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is right every page must have only one h1 and you may use h2 h3 and arrange your data for search engine

all links will be followed and archived in search engine by default except if you tell other by your robot meta tag in every page and not only the main one

you may submit sitemap xml in your website and search engine will submit all your pages.

my advice is to think in search engines in every page with it's content not the whole website, search engines archive and rank website pages, so the good pages friendly to search engine will appear in first results in searching about a content in this pages.

My Regards